# Is 'Credit and Debit Payment' a user-friendly term/word?

Tags: user-expectation, indicator, user-communication, money

First question here, hopefully it's not too shabby.

I'm analysing an app that has account balance system.

I'll try to make a scenario, though this is fictional.

An app acts as a bridge between Bakers and Buyers. In order for Buyers to use the service, buyer Daniel must have money stored inside his account.

Daniel has currently $200 dollars in his account and wish to order some custom wedding cakes from a Baker called Redna.

Daniel also wishes to add more ornaments onto the cakes.

Redna calculates all of the expenses and charges Daniel for $100 to bake the cakes.

Redna goes onto the Custom Wedding Project and click on 'Payment' tab. There, there would be Daniel's account balance and a button called "Make A Debit Payment" button.

Right now, the app is using that wording instead of simply saying "Charge The Account"

Perhaps, because I'm not a native English speaker, ***but is Debit Payment a common term or words to use in this situation?***

They also have "Make A Credit Payment" button which I am proposing to change to "Refund Account" button.

Hope I make myself clear with this.

Comment: What's the scenario for Make a Credit Payment?

Comment: I am confused here, is he paying you $100 or is he adding $100 to his account so that he can have $300 in his account to do something with it

Comment: Who are the users who see the button, what is their role, and what is the terminology *they* use to describe the actions they take?

Comment: Actually the term "user" and "client" is little bit confusing. So please explain your scenario in detail or explain these terminology properly.

Comment: I think these comments here are a good indication that your wording *is* confusing.

Comment: Hey all, sorry for it is kinda confusing. I've just added a fiction scenario. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

'Debit' and 'Credit' are financial terms and, as such, may be required for reasons of legal transparency. I'd check on the before removing them.

If they are *not* legally required then certainly make the language more friendly but be sure that your audience understands what they are being asked to do - financial problems can create legal minefields.

One of the problems I see with your proposed text is the "Make A Credit Payment" vs "Refund Account" - I'm not convinced these two terms are the same thing. "Add Funds" seems more applicable to me but I can't truly be sure of the context.

There is a possibility that the two terms mean something entirely different: Debit vs Credit can mean paying directly from your account vs paying via a credit service.

I can't really stress this enough: When you're dealing with financial language you really need to make sure you get it right and **check everything with legal and financial experts**.